# PHP ZipArchive::addFile битые имена файлов

Tags: php, zip, ziparchive

Вот код:

```
// generate unique archive
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$count = 0;
do {
    if ($count > 10) {
        // TODO: logger
        return false;
    }
    $name = md5(microtime() . rand(0, 9999));
    $filename = $this->tmp_path.$name.'.zip';
    $count++;
} while ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE ) !== true);

// add files to archive
foreach($audioFiles as $audioFile) {
    // TODO: fix file name
    $zip->addFile(SystemHelper::preparePath($audioFile->getPath(false)), Conv::win2utf($audioFile->file));
}
// save archive
if ($zip->close() !== true) {
    // TODO: logger
    var_dump($zip->getStatusString());
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что Zip архивы используют старую кодировку *windows*, для кириллицы ***cp866***.
Все что нужно исправить:

```
$zip->addFile(SystemHelper::preparePath($audioFile->getPath(false)), iconv( "windows-1251", "cp866", $audioFile->file));
```